# How to not select row of duplicate column A when column B and C is unique

Tags: mysql

Not sure how to explain this properly in the title, i might as well show the data.

I have a table **([SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c5272/1))**:

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | session  |  updated   |
+----+----------+------------+
| a  | c9c9c9c9 | 2018-22-03 |
| a  | c9c9c9c9 | 2018-21-03 |
| a  | s9s9s9s9 | 2018-20-03 |
| a  | s9s9s9s9 | 2018-19-03 |
| b  | s8s8s8s8 | 2018-05-02 |
| b  | s8s8s8s8 | 2018-04-02 |
| c  | s7s7s7s7 | 2018-03-01 |
| c  | s7s7s7s7 | 2018-02-01 |
| d  | s2s2s2s2 | 2018-01-01 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Currently i'm using this query

```
SELECT id, 
       session, 
       Max(updated) AS updated_at 
FROM   reports 
GROUP  BY id, 
          session 
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC 
LIMIT  4
```

This is the **[SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c5272/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c5272/1)**

Which is giving me this but i don't want row 2 because it's a duplicate ID

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | session  |  updated   |
+----+----------+------------+
| a  | c9c9c9c9 | 2018-22-03 |
| a  | s9s9s9s9 | 2018-20-03 |
| b  | s8s8s8s8 | 2018-05-02 |
| c  | s7s7s7s7 | 2018-02-01 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

I want a results like this

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | session  |  updated   |
+----+----------+------------+
| a  | c9c9c9c9 | 2018-22-03 |
| b  | s8s8s8s8 | 2018-05-02 |
| c  | s7s7s7s7 | 2018-02-01 |
| d  | s2s2s2s2 | 2018-01-01 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

I tried

```
SELECT a.id,
       (SELECT session
        FROM   reports AS b
        WHERE  b.id = a.id
        LIMIT  1),
       Max(a.updated) AS updated_at
FROM   reports AS a
GROUP  BY a.id
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC
LIMIT  4
```

But my MYSQL just keeps getting timeout with 100% CPU load, I have about 328745+ rows in that table currently.

Answer (score 0):

Use "DISTINCT" when using SELECT to filter duplicate values. Visit this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) to know more about DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify on how the data from `session` column will be selected, because you have `id` and `session` in the `GROUP BY` clause, and there are multiple `sessions` per `id`.

If this is not a concern, just remove `session` in the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
id, 
session,
MAX(updated) AS updated_at 
FROM reports 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY updated_at 
DESC LIMIT 4
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c5272/2)

Comment: I have `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` error

Comment: Can you remove the `session` column in the `SELECT` statement? The SQL Fiddle I added is working properly.